If $P$ and $Q$ are finite, non-empty posets and the poset of order-preserving maps $P^P$ is isomorphic to $Q^Q$, must $P$ be isomorphic to $Q$?
Let $(P,\le_P)$ and $(Q,\le_Q)$ be posets. A function $f:Q\to P$ is order-preserving if whenever $q,q'\in Q$ and $q\le_Q q'$, we have $f(q)\le_P f(q')$. If there is a bijective order-preserving map from $Q$ to $P$ whose inverse is order-preserving, we say $P$ and $Q$ are order-isomorphic. Let $P^Q$ denote the poset of order-preserving maps from $Q$ to $P$, where, for $f,g\in P^Q$,
$$
f\le g\ \text{if for all}\ q\in Q\text{,}\ f(q)\le_P g(q).
$$
Below (see page 54 of the Ph.D. thesis of Dwight Duffus) is $P^P$ where $P$ is the four-element poset $C_4=\{a,b,c,d\}$ with $a,b<c,d$ and no other non-trivial comparabilities.

If $P=\{x,y,z\}$ where $x,z<y$ and $Q=\{a,b,c\}$ where $a,c<b$ are three-element posets with no other comparabilities, then $P^Q$ is below. (The members $f$ of $P^Q$ are written so $f(a)$ is the first letter, $f(b)$ the second, and $f(c)$ the third.)

If $P$ and $Q$ are finite, non-empty posets such that $P^P$ is order-isomorphic to $Q^Q$, must $P$ be order-isomorphic to $Q$?
It is known to be true if $P$ or $Q$ is connected (that is, the graph of the diagram is connected).
If payment can be arranged legally and easily, I offer a prize of \$321 (U.S.; alas, I am not Lavinia Clay) for the first correct solution given before December 31, 2024 (this is not a legally-binding contract and I am the sole arbiter of who wins the prize).
References
Dwight Albert Duffus, "Toward a Theory of Finite Partially Ordered Sets," Ph.D. thesis, University of Calgary (1978).
Dwight Duffus, "Powers of Ordered Sets," Order 1 (1984), 83–92.
Dwight Duffus and Rudolf Wille, "A Theorem on Partially Ordered Sets of Order-Preserving Mappings," Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 76 (1979), 14–16.
Jonathan David Farley, "Does the Endomorphism Poset $P^P$ Determine Whether a Finite Poset $P$ Is Connected? An Issue Duffus Raised in 1978," Mathematica Bohemica 148 (2023), 435–446.

If $P_1,\dots,P_m$ are connected components of $P$, then $P^P$ is a direct sum over functions $g\colon {1,2,\dots,m}\to {1,2,\dots,m}$ of $\prod_{i=1}^m P_i^{P_{g(i)} }$, right?

@FedorPetrov While I can guess, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "direct sum", but $P^P$ as a set is essentially the disjoint union (over all of your functions $g$) of $\prod_{i=1}^m {P_{g(i)}}^{P_i}$. (In our notation, the exponent is the domain of the order-preserving maps and the base is the range.)  We can make this a poset by taking the disjoint sum of all these products and then it would be order-isomorphic to $P^P$.  See Proposition 4.1 on page 193 of McKenzie's 2003 paper for various arithmetic rules. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B:ORDE.0000026529.04361.f8

Yes, direct sum is a disjoint union, and  I certainly had to switch $P_{g(i)}$ and ${P_i}$. So a question arises: if a poset is represented as a direct product in two different ways $P=\prod X_i=\prod Y_i$, is there always a representation $P=\prod Z_i$ which is their "common subdivision"?

@FedorPetrov If I understand your question, the answer is no: For $n\in\mathbb N$, let $\bf n$ be the $n$-element set ${0,1,2,\dots,n-1}$ with the usual order.  Then $({\bf 1}+{\bf 2})\times({\bf1}+{\bf2}^2+{\bf2}^4)\cong({\bf 1}+{\bf 2}^3)\times({\bf1}+{\bf2}+{\bf2}^2)$ even though ${\bf 1}+{\bf 2}$, ${\bf1}+{\bf2}^2+{\bf2}^4$, ${\bf 1}+{\bf 2}^3$, and ${\bf1}+{\bf2}+{\bf2}^2$ are all directly indecomposable posets. But if $P$ is connected, the answer is "yes". This is Hashimoto's Refinement Theorem. See Proposition 3.1 on page 191 of the 2003 McKenzie paper (continued below)

Thank you! You understood properly. In our situation they are all connected. Not that I understand what to do next.

@FedorPetrov (continued from above) for a proof in the case of two factors and Section 10.4 of the text "Ordered Sets: An Introduction" (second edition) by Bernd Schroeder for the case of an arbitrary number of factors. Duffus in his thesis proves a version where not all the factors have to be connected: see Theorem 5 on page 438 of the 2023 paper by Farley. https://mbpapers.math.cas.cz/full/148/4/mb148_4_1.pdf

Let $P$ be a finite poset with connected components $P_1, \dots, P_n$. Let $P_i'$ be $P_i$ with a new bottom element $x_{i,0}$ adjoined. Let $P_i''$ be $P_i'$ with a new element $x_{i,1}$ adjoined above $x_{i,0}$ (but not above anything else). Then let $P_i'''$ be obtained by adding a new element $x_{i,2}$ below $x_{i,1}$. Continue in this manner, building a bunch of very long "zigzags" emanating from each $P_i$ (for each $i$, the zigzag should be the same length $n$). Then identify the endpoints $x_{i,n}$ for various $i$ to a central "hub". Call the resulting poset $P'$.

I think if $n$ is very large compared to $P^P$, then endomorphisms of $P$ should be basically the only way to construct endomorphisms of $P'$. So maybe $P^P \cong Q^Q$ will imply $(P')^{(P')} \cong (Q')^{(Q')}$. Since $P',Q'$ are connected, this would allow a reduction to the previous case.

@TimCampion I am guessing that the $n$ representing the length of the zigzag is different from the $n$ representing the number of components?

@Tri ah yes -- that was the idea. I'm not sure it works though.

The answer is yes. That is, we have:
Theorem: Let $P,Q$ be finite nonempty posets with $P^P \cong Q^Q$. Then $P \cong Q$.
We deduce it from the following:
Lemma 1: Let $P,Q$ be finite nonempty posets. Suppose that $P^P \cong Q^Q$. Then $P \times (n-1) \cong Q \times (m-1)$ where $n$ is the length of a longest chain in $P$ and $m$ is the length of a longest chain in $Q$ (and $n-1$ is a linear poset with $n-1$ elements).
Proof of Theorem: The case where $P$ (equivalently $Q$) is discrete is trivial, so assume that $n$ (equivalently $m$) is $\geq 2$. Apply Lemma 1. We have $m = n$ since since the longest chain in $P \times (n-1)$ is of length $n(n-1)$ and the longest chain in $Q\times (m-1)$ is of length $m(m-1)$, so that $n(n-1) = m(m-1)$. Then use the fact that cartesian product of isomorphism classes of finite posets is cancellative (see e.g. here).
To prove Lemma 1, the strategy will be to identify a subposet of $P^P$ which is isomorphic to $n^P$ where $n$ is a chain of maximal length in $P$.
Lemma 2: The longest length of a chain in $P^P$ is $|P|n$ where $n$ is the length of a longest chain in $P$.
Proof: $|P|n$ is clearly an upper bound for the length of the longest chain, since each link in the chain must lower some element of $P$ by at least one level. To realize this length, choose a particular longest chain $C$ in $P$, and starting from the constant map at the top of $C$, lower one element of $P$ at a time one link at a time down the chain until you get to the constant map at the bottom of $C$.
Observation: Let $D$ be a longest chain in $P^P$. Then for each $p \in P$, there is a longest chain $C_p$ in $P$ such that every $f \in D$ has $f(p) \in C_p$. The chain $D$ has at the top the map sending each $p \in P$ to the top of $C_p$, and each step down lowers some $p \in P$ one link down $C_p$.
Definition: Let $D$ be a longest chain in $P^P$, and $C_p$ the chain associated to $p$ as in the Observation. Then consider the subposet
$$\langle D \rangle = \{f : P \to P \mid \forall p \in P \,f(p) \in C_p \} \subseteq P^P$$
The best case is when $C_p$ is independent of $p$. Not all assignments $p \mapsto C_p$ actually support a longest chain -- I don't know a criterion for exactly which cases do (note though -- there's no condition saying that $p \in C_p$ or anything like that). For example, though, if $P$ has two connected components $P_1,P_2$, each of which contains a unique longest chain $C_1,C_2$, then for any function $f : \{1,2\} \to \{1,2\}$, the formula $C_p = f(i(p))$ where $p \in P_{i(p)}$ supports a longest chain $D_f$, and $\langle D_f \rangle \cong $C_i^P$ is independent of $f$ up to isomorphism in this case.
We will now attempt to reconstruct $\langle D \rangle$ from $D$. The following procedure is guaranteed to work if $C_p$ happens to be independent of $p$. There are a few steps which might break down if $C_p$ varies with $p$, but in each case we will have some way of seeing that it breaks down without knowing what $P$ is, in which case we choose a different $D$ and start over.
Start with $\langle D \rangle_0 = \{f\}$ where $f \in D$ is the top element of $D$. Suppose inductively that $\langle D \rangle_i$ is of the form $\langle D \rangle_i = \{f \in \langle D \rangle \mid \forall p \, f(p) \geq c_{p,i}\}$ for some collection of elements $c_{p,i} \in C_p$. For instance, we can take $c_{p,0}$ to be the top element of $C_p$. Suppose also that $\langle D \rangle_i \cap D$ comprises the top $i+1$ elements of $D$. We also suppose inductively that $\langle D \rangle_i$ is a graded lattice [1], closed under meets and joins in $P^P$. The bottom element of $\langle D \rangle_i$ is the $(i+1)$st-from-top element of $D$.
Now to form $\langle D \rangle_{i+1}$, let $c$ be the $(i+2)$nd-from-top element of $D$, the immediate predecessor in $D$ of the bottom element of $\langle D \rangle_i$. It "should" be the case that there is a unique largest element $a \in \langle D \rangle_i$ such that there exists a unique immediate predecessor $b < a$ in $P^P$ with the property that when you close $\langle D \rangle_i \cup \{b\}$ under meets and joins which exist in $P^P$, you get a distributive lattice, which we call $\langle D \rangle_{i+1}$, such that $\langle D \rangle_{i+1} \cap D$ comprises the $(i+2)$-many highest elements of $D$. In fact, this will be the case if $D$ has the property that $C_p$ is independent of $p$. So we demand that this be the case, and define $\langle D \rangle_{i+1}$ in this way. If it's not the case, we go back and choose a different longest chain $D$ and start over.
Doing this repeatedly, we eventually get a distributive lattice $\langle D \rangle_{n|P|-1}$ containing $D$ an closed under meets and joins in $P^P$. It "should" also be the case that if $a < b$ is an immediate predecessor in $\langle D \rangle_{n|P|-1}$, then it's also an immediate predecessor in $P^P$. In fact this will be the case if $C_p$ is independent of $p$. If it's not the case, then we choose a different $D$ and start over.
Now consider a situation $a < b > c$ where $a,c$ are immediate predecessors of $b$ in $\langle D \rangle_{n|P|-1}$. Then $a$ differs from $b$ in that there is a single $p \in P$ such that $a(p) < b(p)$, and it is one step lower in $C_p$. Similarly, $c(q) < b(q)$ is one step lower in $C_q$, for a single $q$. Suppose that $a$ and $c$ are incomparable. Then $a \wedge b$ must be an immediate predecessor of $a$ and of $b$ in $\langle D \rangle_{n|P|-1}$ because it is graded. So it's also an immediate predecessor of $a$ and of $b$ in $P^P$. Considering that it must be contained in a longest chain in $\langle D \rangle_{n|P|-1}$, which is of length $n|P|$, we can deduce that it must be given exactly by lowering $p,q$ each one step along their respective chains from what $b$ did. So assuming that $a,b,c \in \langle D$, we concluce that $a \wedge b \in \langle D$. Reasoning inductively like this, we conclude that $\langle D \rangle_{n|P|-1} = \langle D \rangle$ (whether or not it's the case that $C_p$ is independent of $D$).
So now we know that for certain longest chains $D$ (including those where $C_p$ is independent of $p$), we have a way of recovering $\langle D \rangle$. Now we formulate a criterion which will tell us if $C_p$ was in fact independent of $p$ (or at least if it's close enough to that case for our purposes):
Lemma 3: Let $D$ be a longest chain in $P^P$ such that the number of elements of $\langle D \rangle$ is maximal. Then $\langle D \rangle \cong C^P$ where $C$ is any particular longest chain of $P$.
Proof: There is an injection $\langle D \rangle \to C^P$ given by identifying the different chains $C_p$ for the various $p \in P$. This injection is an isomorphism iff $\langle D \rangle$ has the maximal possible number of elements.
Proof of Lemma 1: Let $D$ be a longest chain in $P^P$ such that $\langle D \rangle$ is of maximal cardinality. Then $\langle D \rangle \cong n^P \cong (2^{n-1})^P \cong 2^{(n-1) \times P}$ where $n$ is the length of the longest chain, linearly ordered. Now, from $2^{P \times (n-1)}$ we may extract the subposet $(P \times (n-1))^{op}$ (it comprises those elements $F$ such that for all $\{E_i\}_{i \in I} \subseteq 2^{P \times (n-1)}$, we have $F \leq \sup E_i$ iff there is $i$ such that $F \leq E_i$). So we've gotten our hands on a poset isomorphic to $P \times (n-1)$, constructed intrinsically from $P^P$.
[1] A lattice is graded if every element is contained in a longest chain and all longest chains are the same length, so that every element has a well-defined "height" (the index of the element in any maximal chain containing it), and moreover, if $a < b > c$ where $ht(b) = ht(a)+1 = ht(c) + 1$, then either $a = c$ or else $ht(a \wedge c) = ht(a)-1 = ht(c)-1$, and dually for $\vee$. This is true for any finite distributive lattice (and more concretely, it's easy to see this is true of $\langle D \rangle$ in the case where $C_p$ is independent of $p$).

I don’t quite follow the step “Let $D$ be a longest chain in $P^P$. Then for each $p \in P$, there is a longest chain $C_p$ in $P$ such that every $f \in D$ has $f(p) \in C_p$.”  Taking $C_p = { f(p) \mid f \in D }$ is clearly a chain, and I think I agree it’s maximal (although this doesn’t quite seem trivial?), but I certainly don’t see why it should be longest — why couldn’t it be a non-longest maximal chain?  Edit: Ah, I see now (but am leaving this comment in case others have the same trouble): we already know $D$ must have length $n |P|$; and if any $C_p$ was shorter, it couldn’t.
